# My ios App has ratings on itunes connect but not on the app store

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect, rating-system

I currently have two star ratings on my app when I look at it through itunes connect.  However, when I look at it through the app store, there are ZERO ratings.

Why?

Answer (score 0):

Switch your App Store app TO another country:

- sign out using menu
- use the button with the country flag on bottom right

Comment: Only USA is available